# Чтение сессии yii2 на другом движке

Tags: php, yii2, авторизация, сессия, фреймворк

Всем привет!
Делаю общую авторизация для yii2 и самописного движка. С авторизацией через куки справился, а вот на сессиях возникла проблема. Не знаю как получить данные пользователя из сессии yii.
Схема следящая:
- Вся авторизация проходит на поддомене(sub.doamin.local) с yii2
 
- yii передает куку сессии на все поддомны хоста. Куку назвал YIISID
- на домене domain.local стоит самописный фрэймворк, в котором нужно каким то образом прочитать данные из YIISID и тоже начать сессию.
- Файлы сессий yii и самописа лежат в одной месте.

С передачей кук проблем не возникло,как мне и нужно они видны на всех поддоменах.
Проблема только в том как прочитать данные из YIISID.
Знаю что можно взять id сессии из YIISID затем по нему найти файл сессии на диске и уже из файла считать нужные данные, но мне кажется есть более цивилизованный способ.

p.s. Возможно решение плевое, но не пинайте сильно, я плохо знаком с сессиями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['YIISID'])){
    session_id($_COOKIE['YIISID']);
}

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['foo'];
```

Answer (score 1):

для использования сессию нужно стартовать `session_start()`

далее записывай в сессию нужные данные `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'value';`

и далее их можно почесть в любом скрипте `$_SESSION['foo']`